# How do I know a details about video codec used by Blender?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, compression

When I do render animation I can choose a "Video Codec". Is that codec provided by Blender app, OS or is installed with some external app? How can verify what have been used?

[image: Video Codec Option]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender uses Ffmpeg to encode video (https://ffmpeg.org/). The Blender install provides support to read a wide variety of codecs, but offers a limited number of containers and codecs to write. The available codecs may also depend on how blender was compiled, and what other codecs are supported by the operating system you are using. For example on apple's confuser you might find other quicktime codecs (for licensing reasons) than on windoze or linux (to further compound the differences, some linux distributions don't provide ffmpeg support out of the box, like Fedora, again for legal reasons).
As much as we like to use blender for every need, be aware also that there are much better and more flexible encoder only apps out there. Even ffmpeg in terminal (or in many of the different frontends or GUIs) can give you more options (and faster encoding)
.